# First loop entry shows me 1 not 0

Tags: maui

Hello for developers I am try display counter of loop but in spite of C# rules counter DisplayAlert in reverse order. This affliction is only in MAUI. First loop entry shows me 1 not 0.

MauiApp

```
   private void OnCounterClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    DisplayAlert(i.ToString(),"message","cancel");
    }
```

This is problem that confuses me.

I am tried another language Windows Forms App(.NET Framework).

WindowsFormsApp

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    MessageBox.Show(i.ToString());
    }
```

Is ok but I am expected achieve that in MAUI according to C# languages.

Comment: The code you have attempts to show two display alerts at same time. The second one, with 1, is on top. Read about c# async/await methods. You need `await DisplayAlert…`. Which means you need an `async` method.

Comment: Please format your code so it is readable

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve that in MAUI according to C# languages which means First loop entry shows `0`, you need add `async`&`await` as Steve suggested like below:

```
async void OnCounterClicked(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
     for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
     {
           await DisplayAlert(i.ToString(), "message", "cancel");
     }        
}
```